# Filling missing values for categorical feature

Tags: categorical-data, missing-data, data-imputation

In case of continuous variable, the missing values can be filled by the mean of other values, but in case of categorical feature how should we fill in the missing values?

Comment: You could fill by the mode. But filling by mean or by mode is not a sane way of imputation because it artificially lessens the variability. A better approach for categorical data is hot-deck imputation. Another, still better, general (but cumbersome) approach is multiple imputation.

Comment: Have you checked why some of your values are missing? MCAR? MAR? MNAR? In general, you have to address this question before you pick a method to impute your missing values.

Comment: [many similar posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=impute*+categoric*+varia*+answers%3A1)